How can I transfer functions to my components in the storybook8?
I am currently using Storybook8 and have implemented a checkbox component.
I am trying to pass setChecked as a prop to see the checkbox in action when clicked, but I am finding it difficult to implement this even after consulting the Storybook 8 documentation.
How can I set up the component so that I can pass setChecked and know when the checkbox is checked?
CheckBoxComponent
interface checkboxLabelProps {
    checked: boolean;
    setChecked: () => void;
    label?: string;
}
export const CheckboxLabel = ({ check, setChecked, label }: checkboxLabelProps) => {
    return (
        <CheckBoxContainer onClick={() => setChecked()}>
            <CheckboxIcon checked={checked} />
            {label && <CheckBoxLabel>{label}</CheckBoxLabel>}
        </CheckBoxContainer>
    );
};


and my checkbox.stories.tsx
const meta: Meta<typeof CheckboxLabel> = {
    title: 'Input/checkbox',
    component: CheckboxLabel,
    tags: ['autodocs'],
    parameters: {
        layout: 'centered'
    },
    argTypes: {
        label: { control: 'text' }
    },
    decorators: (Story, args) => {
        const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true);
        return <Story {...args} setChecked={() => setChecked(!checked)} />;
    } // not working
} satisfies Meta<typeof CheckboxLabel>;
export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>;

export const CheckIn: Story = {
    args: {
        checked: true,
        label: 'Check'
    }
};


When you click My Components in the Storybook
setChecked is not a function
An error appears.
How do I transfer the function, and can I induce a change in the state with clicks?
